# Arduino analog input to iphone notification

Tags: input, arduino-uno-wifi, analog

I need some help :)

1. Is it even doable?
2. Is there anyone who wants to help me program it?

My wish:
I want to receive a iphone notification when 1 arduino analog input drop from 5 to 0 volt.

Then (later) when the voltage goes back to 5V i want another message.

It needs to be over Wifi (not BT).

Is there anyone that can help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks guys,
I already have the pushsafer app installed, so that comes in quitte handy. You say there is alot to be found for The kind of thing i wanna do.
But what do i search for? And where do i look?
Could you provide me with websites or links?
Or mabye forums where people could help me build the code? Greetings :)

Comment: Regarding your "Could you provide ... Or mabye[sic] forums where people could help me build the code?"  There is an [official Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/).

Answer (score 1):

It is totally doable, but we cannot give detailed tutorials here, since this is a simple Q&A site. So I will point you to a direction, that can lead you to the solution.

When building IOT devices with Arduino (and thats exactly, what you are doing) there are 2 internet services, that are commonly used for getting information from the device to other devices (like your phone):

- Blynk
- IFTTT (means If This Then That)

Both have apps and can be used to push notifications, when your IOT device does a webrequest to the service. There are also libraries for Arduino available (at least for Blynk). There are many tutorials out there, so I suggest, that you search for yourself and try some of them.

For the hardware of your IOT device, I would suggest an ESP board, because they already have Wifi build in, for example the ESP32 gives you great IO capabilities.

Comment: If you only need to send a push-message, you can also use Prowl, Pushbullet, or Pushsafer.